# c++ templates generation times

Tags: function, templates, copy

Hi everyone I've a question about templates in c++.

I would like to explain what I wonder via an example. Lets max() will be our template function:

```
template <typename Type> 
Type max(Type tX, Type tY)
{
    return (tX > tY) ? tX : tY;
}
```

Now, when i call this max in my main, for each call does the compiler generate the function

and replaces the templates type with actual types ?

I mean;

```
int main()
{
int result1,result2;
float result3;

result1=max(3,5);
result2=max(10,12);
result3=max(4.5,12.2);
return 0;
}
```

In here  max will be copied 3 times and replaced its parameters or something else ? Is there anyone who can help me ? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that a compiler typically resolves templates once per data type per compilation unit. And the linker does clever stuff to stop *code bloat*: i.e. multiple copies of the same function across all compilation units are condensed into 1. The early Microsoft C++ linkers didn't bother doing any such thing and the generated code was large.

In your example I would expect two functions to be generated; one with two arguments and one with four.

Ah - I see you've edited the post to have two floating point parameters in the last case rather than four integral types.

Comment: So , according to your answer, the max function will be copied just two times one for int and one for float ? and the second call of int max'll use the first copy of the function ? @Bathsheba

Comment: I don't think a float would be generated at all since your literals are all integral types. The compiler wouldn't give a monkeys about the return type. I might be wrong though.

Comment: sorry for the mistake , the result3 is = max(4.5 , 12.2 ). and now ? @Bathsheba

Comment: Now you'd get two, one with double the other with int.

Comment: If you had the same thing in a different compilation unit you may end up with a total of 4; a good linker will unbloat though.

Comment: Okey, thank you , is there any compiler flag to  control it on my own ?

Comment: That I doubt as templates in C++ are evolving so rapidly.